# how save max length description using lucene 4.10.3?

Tags: java, lucene

I tried to store large description field using lucene 4.10.3.

If I use StringField or TextField 
{

```
doc.add(new StringField("description", rs.getString("description"), Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("description", rs.getString("description"), Store.YES));
```

}
I will receive the following error
{
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one immense term in field="description" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.
}

However if I use 
{

```
doc.add(new Field("description", rs.getString("description"), Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED));
```

}
I will not receive any error but the lucene Field seems to be deprecated in lucene 4.10.3

In conclusion can me point a solution about how to store large text using lucene 4.10.3 ?

Best regards,
Aurelian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the relevant [Lucene JIRA report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5472),

> when a term is greater then 2^15 bytes it is silently ignored at
>   indexing time – a message is logged in to infoStream if enabled,
>   but no error is thrown

So it used to give an *illusion* of this text being indexed (whilst it wasn't), which is now replaced with a proper exception. The fact you haven't noticed this just proves the point.

Indexing such a large amounts of data is unrealistic, you might want to reconsider your data model to fit into the above mentioned boundary.